# urllib2 Request issue

Tags: python, url, request, urllib2

i am trying to open a page using urllib2

```
 req = urllib2.Request("http://1033kissfm.com",
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0'})
 response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
 rstPage = response.read()
```

and the response is

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i open this url in browser its working fine 
this is the url

```
http://1033kissfm.com
```

in browser it redirects to

```
http://www.1033kissfm.com/pages/main
```

page.

Comment: This is web-site specific issue, not a python problem. The site probably looks for headers or other information for proof you are using a web browser, not a script.

Comment: As such, your question is too localized for Stack Overflow; an answer will only help you, not anyone else as it cannot be generalized.

Comment: its python issue if its a bad request why its opening in web browser ?

Comment: You'd have the same problem with Perl, or C, or Java. It is an issue with the website, not the python urllib2 library.

Comment: i am sure its not a library issue nor i am here to proof that , but i am sure i don't now something that can make it able to run though python library

Comment: Yes, but your question is still too localized. We can try and fix your very specific problem with this website (which will take trial and error), but it won't help anyone else.

Comment: main url reponse is 

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=pages/main">

then it redirects to other page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the issue since i think library do not provide any support for handling redirect. this code will help to find redirects for gettting proper response

```
def get_hops(url):
    redirect_re = re.compile('<meta[^>]*?url=(.*?)["\']', re.IGNORECASE)
    hops = []
    while url:
            if url not in hops:
                hops.insert(0, url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            if response.geturl() != url:
                hops.insert(0, response.geturl())
                # check for redirect meta tag
            match = redirect_re.search(response.read())
            if match:
                url = urlparse.urljoin(url, match.groups()[0].strip())
            else:
                url = None
    return hops
```